# I am trying to generate PDF/A-3 using mpdf (PHP library) but when I try to validate the output using an online validator ,the result is not a PDF/A-3

Tags: php, mpdf, pdfa

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'PDFA' => true,
    'PDFAauto' => true,
    //'PDFAversion'=> 'A-3',
]);

$mpdf->SetAssociatedFiles([[
    'name' => 'public_filename.xml',
    'mime' => 'text/xml',
    'description' => 'some description',
    'AFRelationship' => 'Alternative',
    'path' => __DIR__ . '/TaxInvoice.xml'
]]);

$rdf  = '<rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:zf="urn:ferd:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#">'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:DocumentType>INVOICE</zf:DocumentType>'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:DocumentFileName>ZUGFeRD-invoice.xml</zf:DocumentFileName>'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:Version>1.0</zf:Version>'."\n";
$rdf .= '  <zf:ConformanceLevel>BASIC</zf:ConformanceLevel>'."\n";
$rdf .= '</rdf:Description>'."\n";

$mpdf->SetAdditionalXmpRdf($rdf);

$html = '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
';

$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output("mupdf.pdf","D");
```

erros from the validator

-ISO 19005-1:2005
Properties specified in XMP form shall use either the predefined schemas defined in XMP Specification, or extension schemas that comply with XMP Specification

-ISO 19005-1:2005
A file's name dictionary, as defined in PDF Reference 3.6.3, shall not contain the EmbeddedFiles key

-ISO 19005-1:2005
A file specification dictionary, as defined in PDF 3.10.2, shall not contain the EF key

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: did you got any correct answer, how to give or create pdf a-3 with xml file.